# boost::lock does not compile in boost 1.53

Tags: c++, boost, locking

I am compiling a project. It has the following lines :

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock ml(m_meta_mut, boost::defer_lock);
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock tl(m_tables_mut, boost::defer_lock);
    boost::lock(ml, tl);
```

I am getting `lock is not a member of boost` on the third line. I am using boost1.53 (the project recommends 1.49)

What is the problem

Comment: The error message is stating that there is no `lock()` function taking those arguments in the `boost` namespace. Perhaps it's in a deeper namespace instead, or you forgot to `#include` the proper header, or you have the arguments wrong or in the wrong order, or ...

Comment: @twalberg: for "you have the arguments wrong or in the wrong order" there's a different error message. This one says that the compiler doesn't know what a `boost::lock` is, period.

Comment: I understand the error and what things might be causing it. I was looking for some insight as to the lock function in boost and what has changed from versions 48 to 53

Comment: #include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/lock_algorithms.hpp>    Does it work when you put this at the top of your file?

Comment: the `boost::lock()` functions are [defined in `boost/thread/locks.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_functions.lock_multiple)

Comment: @bennofs thanks, that fixed the issue. I dont know so much about threading and locks in boost (yet), so did not know why the error was coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning my comment into more of a complete answer. The `boost::lock()` functions are [defined in boost/thread/locks.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_functions.lock_multiple). When you see the compiler error

> error: ‘lock’ is not a member of ‘boost’

the compiler cannot find a function `lock()` in the `boost` namespace. 
The solution is to add `#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>` in whatever translation unit you are compiling.

I don't see changes to this header from boost 1.49 to boost 1.53, though I didn't look extensively. It's possible include directives have changed.

**Edit:**
Still the same in 1.67